# TextReader.ReadToEnd vs Stream.CopyTo

Tags: c#

I have request of concatenating text files over 500MB.

The legacy code given to me uses TextReader.ReadToEnd() with code below:

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(concatenatedFile, false, fEncoding))
{
    foreach (string filename in filesToConcatenate)
    {
        using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default))
        {
            textWriter.Write(textReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the code above to use Stream.CopyTo() with File.OpenRead.
To justify the change, one thing I can think of OutofMemoryException I hit when ReadToEnd() is used for very large files.

ReadToEnd() gives me an impression it will read to the end, save whole text chunk (in this case, 500MB ??) into memory then write to the designated stream.

So my questions are:
how does Stream.CopyTo() behave differently than ReadToEnd() in very large file concatenation? what will determine size of text each time Stream.CopyTo() copies into stream? Would using this instead of ReadToEnd() prevent OutOfMemoryException in most cases?

Here is the code I want to use instead:

```
using (Stream output = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(outputFile))
{
    foreach (string inputFile in inputFiles)
    {
        using (Stream input = System.IO.File.OpenRead(inputFile))
        {
            input.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll be breaking any character set handling if you're simply concatenating streams and hoping the nothing breaks. Files could be different character sets or contain BOM that will upset simple stream based concatenation. Your best best would be to use StreamReader.ReadLine and StreamWriter.WriteLine.

Comment: Mostly you only concat log files with the same format/character sets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CopyTo will copy in blocks (4096 = default size), ReadToEnd will read all data before it's written. So a 1gb file will be read totally with the ReadToEnd() method. So for large files, i'll advice CopyTo.

The CopyTo has a overload method to specify the blocksize.

Stream.CopyTo Method (Stream, Int32) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783870.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783870.aspx) copies the data in blocks. The (Stream, int) overload allows you to specify the size of the buffer, but the default is 4096 bytes.

`TextReader.ReadToEnd` will read the entire file into memory, so in this case, `Stream.CopyTo` will be much more memory efficient.